# Why is VS often not (re)building my Qt project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have a problem with Qt and MSVS 2013. When building my project, the compiler only creates an empty build folder. Compile output:

16:30:45: Running steps for project MyCoolProjectName...
16:30:45: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
16:30:45: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"
16:30:45: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
16:30:45: Elapsed time: 00:00.

When I wait a minute and try again, it is working sometimes. Is there something I must configure?

Update: When i clean my project (build -> clean all) and after that i press run (ctrl + R), the application starts. So, the output is not cleaned up, and the compiler isn't rebuilding. It seems like this is an cleanup issue. Manually removing the build output folder doesn't help.

Comment: Is this a virtual machine or is your system clock screwed up somehow? Does this happen on a fresh boot? That  being said, do the source files actually change between rebuilds or are you just clicking the build button for no reason? VS will not rebuild your code unless something changed and the object files need to be updated.

Comment: No this is no virtual machine. It happens also with a fresh boot. It's not a problem with the system clock i guess. I get this output immediately after i started the build process. Also when i changed source files, i get this fault.